# Haskell: Getting a single bit from a String of bits

Tags: haskell

So I'm using a Grey-code generator to generate all possible bit Strings of length 6.  The generator is as follows:

```
gray :: Integer -> String
gray n
 | n == 0 = [""]
 | n >  0 = map (++"0") (gray (n-1)) ++
            map (++"1") (reverse (gray (n-1)))

recipes = gray 6
```

Then, I'm attempting to get a specific bit from each of these Strings and convert that bit to an Integer.  I'm doing this in the following way:

```
cost' :: String -> Cost
cost' r i = toInteger( ord ( r!!i ) )
```

Now, for some reason this isn't working.  Regardless of what 'i' value I use, the function cost' will either result in 48 (if the bit in position 2 of the list is 0 --> ex. '100000') or 49 (if the bit in position 2 of the list is 1 --> ex. '101000').

It doesn't make any sense to me why this is.. It's my understanding that Strings are stored as lists in Haskell, and that to get a certain element 'i' from a list 'r' in Haskell, you execute 'r!!i'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `ord` returns the code point number of the character, and `'0'` is code point 48, `'1'` is code point 49. The function you want to use is [`digitToInt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Data-Char.html#v:digitToInt).